# How to Check filename

Tags: java, filenames, filereader

I have a method that reads filename for a file  from a certain source. My method should handle two types of files. My next method depends on the name of the file.

`_InPayed.txt"  "_OutPayed.txt`

My problem is how to check if the filename is `..._inpayed` Or `..._OutPayed`
How to check the string after the strick " _"

### Code:

```
public class FilenameDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       final String FPATH = "/home/mem/"filename.txt";
       System.out.println("Extension = " + myHomePage.extension());
       System.out.println("Filename = " + myHomePage.filename());
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at methods of the String class?

Answer (score 1):

No need for subString. A simple call to `contains(...)` is all you need. More importantly, learn to use the API.

```
if (myString.toLowerCase().contains("inpayed")) {
  // do something
}
```

- [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: what if the file is called `InPayed_OutPayed.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()` method to extract a desired part of a file name stored as `String`. Or if the part you are checking will always be at the end of the `String` a simpler option is to use `endsWith()`. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for details about the method usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the certain string in the file name then use `contains` method.

&

You can get the file name after `_` using below expression

```
System.out.println("Filename = "+FPATH.substring(FPATH.lastIndexOf("_")+1,FPATH.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The string must contain one and only one `_` for this to work.

```
String fullFile="whatever_InOutPayed.txt"
String[] split = file.split("_");
// split[0] = "whatever"
// split[1] = "InOutPayed.txt"
String file = split[1];
```

If it contains more than one then take the last element of the array

```
String file = split[split.length - 1];
```

or you can easily use [`String.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).